# Any research done on relationship between fertility rate and wealth?

Tags: reference-request, population-economics

I am discussing about evolution theory with a philosophy student and she observes that wealthier families tend to have fewer children, which kind of goes against natural selection, i.e. the genes of smarter/healthier people do not necessarily pass along the generations.

Now I am thinking:

- Is there really such a pattern? If yes,
- Does it vary across different environments (e.g. developed vs developing countries)?
- What is the economics explanation?

References to papers are very welcome.

I am not sure how to tag this question, feel free to edit.

Comment: Smarter has very little to do with wealthier. And I strongly recommend refraining from socio-biological speculation.

Comment: In a short time one of you will argue that idiocracy is real (see https://xkcd.com/603/). But it is not. Intelligence is a welcome trait in all social environments. The phenomenon you describe may only result in fewer children bringing a good educational background from home.

Comment: Again, we are just pointing out that you claim that wealth means smart/healthy. Let us cast aside this assumption. There are papers that deal with income and fertility. http://www.econ.yale.edu/~pschultz/cdp925.pdf

Comment: This may help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_fertility_rate#/media/File:Trends_in_TFR_1950-2050.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Population changes slowly over time but has large effects in the long-run.
Here are some well-studied **facts about fertility**:

- Before the industrial revolution, the rich had more surviving children than the poor.
- The transition from stagnation to economic growth is accompanied by a demographic transition from high to low fertility.
- Today, both within and across countries, rich and educated mothers have less children than poor and unskilled ones.
- Most of the literature finds that the income of the father positively affects fertility, while the income of the mother negatively affects fertility.

Economists would stress that **one explanation** among others is Parents' income: Opportunity cost of child-rearing time is high for high income/education mothers. They are other reasons.

David de la Croix works on this topic and offers interesting lectures on Fertility, Education, Growth and Sustainability [here](http://perso.uclouvain.be/david.delacroix/cicse.html). You will find references for the above facts and other reasons for the decline in fertility.

An academic reference is: De la Croix D. and M. Doepke, Inequality and growth: why differential fertility matters, American Economic Review, 93, 1091-1113, 2003.